# Is mdconfig in FreeBSD equivalent to zRAM in linux? Has anyone done any experiments porting zRAM to freeBSD from linux mainline?

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, freebsd

My requirement is to minimize or fasten the page swapping in freeBSD, I came across zRAM in linux, so I was wondering if mdconfig does the same? I see it creates virtual drives as disk, but does it allocate bloaks in RAM, how will be performance compared to zRAM?

Answer (score 0):

zram is intended as a backend... now.  it could work to that end but there is no md in the program so you will need equally old binaries. such as link, unlink, mknod, losetup... oh yeah, and zram.  make sure to read all of the documentation, man pages, info.... tends to answer your questions for you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32688857)